# Google map (and VZ Navigator) rotates in wrong direction

Tags: 2.2-froyo, navigation, google-maps-navigation, calibration, htc-droid-incredible-2

When I use Google Navigation or VZ Navigator on a Droid Incredible 2 it is supposed to align the map to the direction I am pointing the phone. But when I turn around the map rotates in the wrong direction. It seems to work fine in Compass applications but not in Google Maps or VZ Navigator and not with other augmented reality apps.

I went to VZ store and saw that other Incredible-2 phone has the same issue, but Thunderbolt and some Samsung phone do not.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems to be a known issue :(( http://community.htc.com/na/htc-forums/f/124/t/11224.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to Gingerbread (Android 2.3) resolves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happens a lot to me. I wish I had a more technical answer but it seems like the compass needs to be reset and shaking it hard for a few seconds usually resets mine. I've had to shake it, reboot, and reopen the app and it comes back fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calibrating the compass? Settings->Location & Security->Calibrate Compass

Answer (score 0):

Hold the phone flat and make a figure 8, do this a few times. These are the instructions found in this app: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.apksoftware.compass